# collections.deque: why q[9999] is faster than q[-1]?

Tags: python, cpython, deque

If I were a programmer writing this functionality, I would implement it as negative means start from right, positive means start from left, which will result in q[-1] much faster than q[9999].

However, as -1 transformed to 1 step from right seems no more time consuming than transform 9999 to 1 step from right, so why does q[-1] is slower than q[9999]?

Thanks

```py
>>> q = collections.deque()
>>> q.extend(range(10000))
>>> %timeit q[-1]
50.7 ns ± 0.195 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
>>> %timeit q[9999]
40.5 ns ± 0.528 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you implement `__getitem__` in Python, you receive whatever index the caller used, without modification.

However, [under the hood](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.0/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#L1540), `collections.deque` implements the C API [sequence protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#sequence-object-structures), and the C API sequence protocol version of `__getitem__` works differently. If you pass in a negative number, Python will add the `len` of the sequence to your index before passing it to the `deque`'s item retrieval implementation.

With both `q[-1]` and `q[9999]`, the index the deque receives is `9999`, and it has to decide whether to iterate from the left or the right to find the element you asked for. However, `q[-1]` has an extra layer of overhead first.

Comment: As both will use the `BINARY_SUBSCR` opcode, is there any way to get the hint of the intermediate step for negative index without reading source?

Comment: @heemayl: If a C type supports slicing, or indexing with anything other than a single integer, then it has to implement the mapping protocol version of `__getitem__`, which doesn't have this index translation. If it only supports integer indexing, then it's probably using the sequence protocol. I don't think there's any fully general way to be sure without reading the source or making direct C API calls (which you can do with ctypes), though. (Also, on Python 2, the sequence protocol supports basic 2-arg slicing, so on Python 2, basic slicing support doesn't rule out the sequence protocol.)